# How to format date to Fri-05 Aug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have followed the Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/df100103.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007972-SW1) and I am having no success:

```
- (NSString *)formatDepartureDateForColumn:(NSDate *)departureDate
{
    NSString *result;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"%a-%d %b"]; 
    result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: departureDate];

    [dateFormatter release];
    return result;

}
```

Anyone have any ideas?  I want the date formatted like this Fri-05 Aug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you refer to is for OS X **10.3 and earlier**.  Try:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"E-dd MMM"]
```

See [*Date Formatters for OS X and iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html). Since 10.4 [unicode formats](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) have been used.